# FastReport.OpenSource.Web support .Net Core 3.0?

Tags: asp.net-core-3.0, fastreport

I have this problem when I render the report. I render the report like this:

```
    @ViewBag.WebReport.Render();

    var webReport = new WebReport(); 
webReport.Report.Load(@"\report.frx"); 
foreach (var item in paramether) { 
      webReport.Report.SetParameterValue(item.Key, item.Value); 
} 
webReport.Report.RegisterData(datos, "Mydata");
 ViewBag.WebReport = webReport;

**System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1+AsyncStateMachineBox1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString,FastReport.Web.WebReport+d__107]**
```

Comment: I found the problem  I need to add await
 @await ViewBag.WebReport.Render();

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem I need to add await @await ViewBag.WebReport.Render();